# Cannot bind function from abstract class in c++

Tags: c++, function, c++11, abstract-class, stdbind

I'm try to use `std::bind` with a virtual pure function in a abstract class but 
I use a design pattern call strategy, because I want make a program that can handle dynamic switch between the game.

I don't get the syntax. here is the code :

Here is my interface class

```
class IGame
{
  public:
    virtual ~IGame(){};
    virtual void move_up(INFO &info)=0;
}
```

By the way `INFO` is a define :

```
 #define INFO std::pair<struct GetMap*, struct WhereAmI*>
```

Here is my control class in it's constructor I call `std::bind` call;

```
 class CGame
  {
  private:
    IGame                                       *game;
    int                                         score;
    std::pair<struct GetMap*, struct WhereAmI*> info; // game information

    std::vector<std::function<void(std::pair<struct GetMap*, struct WhereAmI*>&)>> ptr_move_ft; //function pointer vector

  public:
    CGame();
    ~CGame();
    void return_get_map(INFO &info);
  }
```

This is the constructor of `CGame` class :

```
CGame::CGame()
 {
   game = new Snake();
   this->info = std::make_pair(init_map(MAP_PATH_SNAKE,0), game->init_player());

   ptr_move_ft.push_back(std::bind(&CGame::return_where_i_am, this,std::placeholders::_1)); //this work

   ptr_move_ft.push_back(std::bind(&game->move_up, game, std::placeholders::_1)); //this create a error
 }
```

So the second `push_back` makes this error :

```
source/CGame.cpp: In constructor ‘arcade::CGame::CGame()’:
source/CGame.cpp:131:44: error: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of a bound member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say ‘&arcade::IGame::move_up’ [-fpermissive]
     ptr_move_ft.push_back(std::bind(&game->move_up, game, std::placeholders::_1));
```

How can I do ?

Sorry for my poor English and c++ code.

Comment: please dont use `#define` when a `typedef` will do

Comment: your question isnt that clear, because the compiler already says that you cannot do it. You should rephrase the question to ask for what you actually want to achieve. As it is now it cannot be fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the expression `&game->move_up` in this line:

```
ptr_move_ft.push_back(std::bind(&game->move_up, game, std::placeholders::_1));
```

This expression is trying to create a pointer-to-member-function, but these pointers are not bound to a particular instance.  Creating a pointer-to-member-function from a particular instance therefore makes no sense, similar to trying to invoke a static method through an instance.

Instead of `&game->move_up` you should use `&IGame::move_up`.

You can also use `&std::decay<decltype(*game)>::type::move_up`.  The advantage is that this expression will adjust to match the type of `*game`, looking for an instance method named `move_up` on whatever the pointed-to type is.  The disadvantage is that the syntax is a bit obtuse.

([Here is a demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1563647ecc164ab8) that shows how both approaches will yield an identical pointer-to-member-function.)

Comment: Thanks you very much !